# Showing that $(I+J)/(I\cap J)\cong (I+J)/I\times (I+J)/J$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

> Show that $(I+J)/(I\cap J)\cong (I+J)/I\times (I+J)/J$, where $I,J$ are ideals in a commutative ring $R$ with identity.

What I did was first show that $\phi: I+J\to (I+J)/I\times (I+J)/J$ defined by $\phi(r+s)=(r+s+I,r+s+J)$ is a ring homomorphism, and then I applied the first isomorphism theorem.

I only showed that $\phi$ is well-defined and operation-preserving before applying the first isomorphism theorem. I also found that $ker(\phi)=I\cap J$.

Is this sufficient enough to show it is an isomorphism? My teacher said I need to show it is surjective too. Why?

Comment: The first isomorphism theorem says that if $\phi: R \longrightarrow S$ is a ring homomorphism with kernel $I$,. then $R/I \cong \text{Im}(\phi)$. So for your proof to work you need to show that the image of the map is your ring on the right side, in other words you need to show that it is onto.

Comment: I think you try to use the fundamental theorem of homomorphism: $R/\mathrm {Ker}\, \phi \cong \mathrm {Im}\, \varphi$, so you need to show that $\mathrm {Im }\, \varphi= (I+J)/I \times (I+J)/J$, i.e. the mapping is surjective.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I get it now! I will make sure to remember to show surjectivity.